# Get last component of pathname in Common Lisp

Tags: directory, common-lisp, pathname

While I can build a pathname e.g.

```
(make-pathname :directory '(:RELATIVE "dir" "subdir" "subsubdir"))
```

how do I get back `subsubdir` from a pathname like this (assuming it is a directory)? I need to extract the last dir from a pathname, just as this Unix command does:

```
$ basename /usr/local/share/
share
```

Answer (score 8):

See the Common Lisp Hyperspec, the [Filenames Dictionary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/c_filena.htm)

```
(first (last (pathname-directory some-pathname)))
```

Comment: This only handles the case where the path ends with a slash. If you have a path `a/b/c`, the code above will return `b` while basename returns `c`.

Comment: @KevinChen: he was asking using Lisp pathnames. The Unix basename command was just an example.

Comment: @KevinChen If the path does not end with a slash, use `(file-namestring "/a/b/c")` instead.